# How to set conditional format to color each second row with phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Does somebody know how set conditional format with phpspreadsheet that each second row is shadowed like in the picture below?

[sorry, I had to delete all the data, but I think its clear what I've meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7UtP.png)

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like there is no "function" inside phpspreadsheet to color the background of each 2nd row(?). If somebody knows such an easy way I'm still interested. In the meantime see my own amateurish way:

As long as you have the variables $col and $rowNumber available somewhere inside your script you can loop thrue all lines and set a background color for all lines with an odd number. Even lines you could address with the "else part".

```
if ($rowNumber%2) {
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col.$rowNumber)->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('e2efda'); //e2efda
        };
```